# Function returning before completing [Swift] [Firebase]

Tags: swift, firebase, function, coordinates

I'm trying to read data from a Google Firebase Database, and I'm realizing that my function is returning before the data has been read.
Here is the code

```
func getFirebaseCoordinates(increment : Int) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    var coordinates : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
    let ref = Database.database().reference()

    ref.child("\(getPilot() + String(increment))/Latitude").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        let lat = snapshot.value as? CLLocationDegrees
        coordinates.latitude = lat ?? -1.0
        print(coordinates.latitude)
    }
    ref.child("\(getPilot() + String(increment))/Longitude").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        let long = snapshot.value as? CLLocationDegrees
        coordinates.longitude = long ?? -1.0
        print(coordinates.longitude)
    }
    print(coordinates)
    return coordinates
}
```

When I retrieve the coordinates, I print them, and then at the end of the function, I print what I am returning.  I actually loop through this function twice, and before I can even print out the first coordinates that I retrieve, I have printed both return statements which come out as "CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)"
Any thoughts? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return completion handler in async functions because return execute before you get async call result

```
func getFirebaseCoordinates(increment : Int,completion: @escaping (CLLocationCoordinate2D)-> Void )  {
    var coordinates : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
    let ref = Database.database().reference()

    ref.child("\(getPilot() + String(increment))/Latitude").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (latitudeSnapshot) in

        let lat = latitudeSnapshot.value as? CLLocationDegrees
        coordinates.latitude = lat ?? -1.0

        ref.child("\(getPilot() + String(increment))/Longitude").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (LongitudeSnapshot) in
             let long = LongitudeSnapshot.value as? CLLocationDegrees
             coordinates.longitude = long ?? -1.0

            completion(coordinates)
         }



    }

}
```